# Accessing A User's Home Directory Through the Web

Tags: user-profile, active-directory

Our school board is set up with Active Directory and we'd like to be able to allow staff to access their files from home through a web interface.  Is it possible to securely expose a user's home directory through Sharepoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it requires some heavy customization/development. I do not recommend it though.

Instead you should utilize the My Site feature of SharePoint, which allows the users to store and work with documents in a better way

Comment: Thanks very kindly.  Heavy customization may come later.  This is our first Sharepoint deployment and we're on a tight schedule.

Comment: In that case I would recommend setting up MySites and providing some information on how users can use their site instead of their home directories. Also how to migrate them to their site (using upload).